# href doesn't work when using data-toggle="tab"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a menu.jsp file which is included in file A and B. This file contains a menu that looks like below. Thanks to data-toggle="tab" the chosen tab is active. However I also want to go to that particular page using the href. This doesn't work. Kan anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
<ul id="navbar_menu" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="filea.jsp">A</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="fileb.jsp">B</a></li>
</ul>
```

I added the following in the head:

```
<link
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have added the following in the bottom of the body:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
‌​
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

I have a javascript file for facebook and twitter:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        !function(d, s, id) {


var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/
                    .test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

The menu.css file is just:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body{
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
}

h1{
    color: red;
}

span{
    color: blue;
}


#my_profile{

    class:"active";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }   
    #navbar_menu {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: That code by itself, when I tested it, works just file (assuming there is a .jsp file somewhere for it to link to). It is possible some other part of your code is messing with it in some way? Do you have Javascript running on the page or a `.htaccess` file that might be redirecting you somewhere?

I guess the real question is what do you mean "doesn't work". The link doesn't do anything? Does it go to an empty page? That sort of thing. What do you expect it to do and what is it doing.

Comment: It doesn't work means that the href doesn't do anything. The path of the page is not changed. If I remove data-toggle="tab" then the href works. This means that I am redirected to filea.jsp (if that is the one I clicked)

Comment: Okay. As I said, when I just copy and paste that code, the href works fine, so there must be some other code therein that is messing it up. Can you provide your css/Javascript related to it?

Comment: I have updated the question and provided you the javascript and css. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The `href` to a page is not going to work, because you are using bootstrap and the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute indicates that you are using a `href` for a `tab`.

Bootstrap expects that you are using a reference to a section inside the same html, like `href="#yourDiv"`.

More details on how bootstrap handles the `data-toggle="tab"` are in the bootstrap js code, check [here](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js). 
There you could find that bootstrap prevents default `href` behavior and use it to load the desired data.

If you are trying to load a page inside the section related to a boostrap tab, you could achieve this using jQuery, example:

HTML:

```
<ul id="navbar_menu" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#diva">A</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#divb">B</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="diva">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="divb">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#diva').load('filea.jsp');
$('#divb').load('fileb.jsp');
```